# Allow script tag in editor Head - CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to inject contents js inside editor. I am able to add script tag inside head tag and it appears, but when i change the source it is removed.

If not possible what is the event name of source mode switch?

Thanks

Comment: Inside editor code or inside textarea content?

Comment: Inside editor code ( classic editor with iframe )